# Error copying file from Linux folder to Google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to copy a file from a Linux folder to a Google cloud storage bucket on Google cloud platform.

I have to do it in a Python module not by command line so `gsutil` does not work.

I have tried:

```
import gcsfs, os
os_path = os.path.join('/venv/lib/python3.9./site-packages/MY_PACKAGE/', 'a_model.py')
gcs_bucket_path = os.path.join('gs://MY_BUCKET/work_folder/', 'model.py')
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
fs.cp_file(os_path, gcs_bucket_path) # error: FileNotFound
# shutil.copyfile() does not work
```

It seems that `gcsfs` can only do the file copy between gcs buckets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python then you should definitely use the [GCS library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) provided by Google. [This](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/samples/snippets/storage_upload_file.py) is a link to the sample you'd need, just modify the snippet to match your needs.

Code looks like the following:

```
import sys
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    # Optional: set a generation-match precondition to avoid potential race conditions
    # and data corruptions. The request to upload is aborted if the object's
    # generation number does not match your precondition. For a destination
    # object that does not yet exist, set the if_generation_match precondition to 0.
    # If the destination object already exists in your bucket, set instead a
    # generation-match precondition using its generation number.
    generation_match_precondition = 0

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name, if_generation_match=generation_match_precondition)

    print(
        f"File {source_file_name} uploaded to {destination_blob_name}."
    )
```